# What is the correct way of handling mimetypes in django

Tags: python, django, mime-types

Currently we are doing something like this for inbound data:

```
    content_type = request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', '')
    mime_type, mime_subtype, mime_params = mimeparse.parse_mime_type(content_type)
    if mime_type == "application" and mime_subtype== "json":
        encoding = mime_params.get("charset", "utf-8")
        return json.loads(request.raw_post_data.decode(encoding))
    elif ...
```

Which looks like it might be right, although it's surprising that we're using a third party library and not something from Django or Python standard.

On the outbound side it looks like this:

```
    accept = request.META.get('HTTP_ACCEPT', "*/*")
    content_type = mimeparse.best_match(["application/json", ...], accept)
    if content_type == "application/json":
        content_type = "{0}; charset=utf-8".format(content_type)
        raw = json.dumps(data)
        return content_type, raw
    elif ...
```

Which doesn't look right, especially the format call.

What is the correct way of doing this stuff?

Comment: [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Django Rest Framework has nothing to do with this.

Comment: My misunderstanding. I look forward to your answer.

Comment: Well it's at least true that Django Rest Framework must handle this somehow.

Comment: here's how: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/negotiation.py#L34-L67